# window.open with a delay

Tags: javascript, popup

I am trying to open an external link in a modal. The following code works fine:

```
$('[data-link]').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    window.open(link, 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250');
});
```

But if I put the `window.open` function inside a delayed function call, I get a "Pop-up blocked" message on my browser:

```
$('[data-link]').on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    _.delay(function(){
        window.open(link, 'newwindow', 'width=300, height=250');
    }, 0);
});
```

It doesn't matter how much the delay is, it just doesn't work with a delayed call. Does anyone know why this happens and how I can make it work?

Comment: You're fighting the popup blocker.  You will not win.

Comment: @SLaks I don't need to fight it without the delay though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popup blockers will only allow you to open a popup in *direct* response to user events.

Once you call `setTimeout()`, you're no longer in direct response to an event and can't get through.

Comment: Thanks, could you please add a link to the documentation as well?